# shell script that notes timestamps and runs a command every 15min and sends the result to a .txt

Tags: shell

Doin a experiment on Tor and messuring the performance of the network. I would need a script that notes timestamps and runs a command "proxychains iperf3 -c "ip address" and send the result to a .txt . I need to run this every 15min 24/7. It´s getting annoying to stay awake. Thansk !

Comment: Look at `crontab`. This is a scheduler for Unix. And redirect output with `>> /path/file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with something like the following:

```
touch mylogfile.txt
while true
do
    proxychains iperf3 -c "ip address"  >> mylogfile.txt
    sleep 900
done
```

if you want to run it without crontab

Comment: Did as you wrote and the script works fine but in the logFile it only say proxychains-3.1. do you know another way of doin it ?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have proxychains and cannot test it. It might be that part of output goes to the standard error stream. In this case, you should add `2>&1` to the redirection in bash/sh/ksh.